# Regex length validation: Ignore leading and trailing whitespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I'm trying to limit our users between 5 and 1024 characters per post.

We are currently using asp.net RegularExpressionValidator for this.

This is kinda working if I set the expression to the following:

```
body.ValidationExpression = string.Format("^[\\s\\S]{{{0},{1}}}$",
        MinimumBodyLength,
        MaximumBodyLength);
```

However, this does not take NewLines and leading/tailing/multiple spaces into account. So users can type stuff like:
Ok *(three spaces)* . (dot), and it will still be validated because three spaces count as characters. The same goes for newlines. We can also type a single . (dot) followed by 5 spaces/newlines.

I have tried multiple regex variations I've found around the web, but none seem to fit my needs exactly. I want them to type minimum 5 characters, and maximum 3000 characters, but I don't really care how many newLines and spaces they use.

To clearify, I want people to be able to type:

```
Hi,
My name is ben
```

I do not want them to be able to type:

```
Hi                  .
```

or

```
A              B
```

(lots of newlines or spaces)

It is possible that regex might not be the way to go? If so, how can I search and replace on the string before the regex evaluates (while still catch it in the validator with the old expression)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the regex below:

```
body.ValidationExpression = string.Format("^((\S)|((\s+|\n+|(\r\n)+)+\S)|(\S(\s+|\n+|(\r\n)+))+){{{0},{1}}}$",
    MinimumBodyLength,
    MaximumBodyLength);
```

It treats as single entity either a single character or single character after (or before) any number of whitespace characters.

Comment: Currently, now it blocks things like "a (5 newlines)", but i doesn't let "a (two newlines) abcvd" through validation. It kinda has to allow people typing with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you problem, you want to count only word characters. If that's the point, you could try this:

```
body.ValidationExpression = string.Format("^\w{{{0},{1}}}$",
MinimumBodyLength,
MaximumBodyLength);
```

Comment: this regex does not allow any whitespace character. the problem is not to count whitespace characters